# Big O Analysis with Recursion Tree of Stooge Sort

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to find the Big O for stooge sort. From Wikipedia

```
algorithm stoogesort(array L, i = 0, j = length(L)-1)
     if L[j] < L[i] then
         L[i] ↔ L[j]
     if j - i > 1 then
         t = (j - i + 1)/3
         stoogesort(L, i  , j-t)
         stoogesort(L, i+t, j  )
         stoogesort(L, i  , j-t)
     return L
```

I am bad at performance analysis ... I drew the recursion tree

[image]

I believe the ... :

- height: `log(n)`
- work on level 0: n    // do I start from level 0 or 1?
- work on level 1: 2n
- work on level 2: 4n
- work on level 3: 8n
- work on level log(n): `(2^log(n))n = O(n^2)`? `2^log2(n) = n`, but its what does `2^log3(n)` actually give?

So its `O(n^2 * log(n)) = O(n^2)`? Its far from Wikipedia's `O(n^(log3/log1.5))` ...

Comment: Let's just say that result is not trivial to arrive at :) I might try and explain it but it's kind of late

Comment: How is `O(n^2 log(n))` equal to `O(n^2)`?

Comment: Also O(n^2 * logn) is still O(n^2 * logn) because that's one entire factor so you're not too far off.

Comment: @Kerrek, in Big O, i keep only the highest "degree" (Forgot the proper term: `log(n) < n^2`), No? **UPDATE**: Oh ya... its not a plus ...

Comment: @JesusRamos: It's quite far off. `n^2 log(n)` grows more slowly than `n^(2 + epsilon)` for any positive `epsilon`.

Comment: @KerrekSB but its closer than his initial n^2

Comment: @JesusRamos: Only in a very specific sense of "closer"... in some way, "no". If you are thinking of the value of the exponent in the power law, then multiplying by `log(n)` doesn't get you *any* closer, if you like.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah I know. I'm actually looking at my lecture notes where I proved this once before. I think the tree height is not actually logn (I may be wrong, I only did this once to scare some people :P )

Comment: @JesusRamos, I think the height is actually `log base3 (n)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size of the problem at level k is (2/3)<sup>k</sup>n. The size at the lowest level is 1, so setting (2/3)<sup>k</sup>n = 1, the depth is k = log<sub>1.5</sub> n (divide both sides by (2/3)<sup>k</sup>, take logs base 1.5).

The number of invocations at level k is 3<sup>k</sup>. At level k = log<sub>1.5</sub> n, this is 3<sup>log<sub>1.5</sub>n</sup> = ((1.5)<sup>log<sub>1.5</sub>3</sup>)<sup>log<sub>1.5</sub> n</sup> = ((1.5)<sup>log<sub>1.5</sub>n</sup>)<sup>log<sub>1.5</sub> 3</sup> = n<sup>log<sub>1.5</sub>3</sup> = n<sup>log 3/log 1.5</sup>.

Since the work at each level increases geometrically, the work at the leaves dominates.

Comment: Ok, how did you calculate the height `k`? I did http://i.imgur.com/Yk8yP.png. Can is `log base 2/3 (1/n) == log base 1.5 (n)`? Which logarithmic formula did you use?

Comment: @jiewmeng log base b of x is log x/log b, and log (1/x) = -log x. We have log_(2/3) (1/n) = log (1/n) / log (2/3) = -log n / -log 3/2 = log_1.5 n.

Comment: How do we come up with the number 2/3 in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to find this answer.
We can see from the Algorithm that the recurrence relation is:

T(n) = 3*T(2/3 n) + 1

Applying the theorem:

f(n) = 1 = O(n<sup>c</sup>), where c=0.
a = 3, b = 3/2 => log3/2(3) =~ 2.70

Since c < log3/2(3), we are at Case 1 of the Theorem, so:

T(n) = O(n<sup>log3/2(3)</sup>) = O(n<sup>2.70</sup>)

Answer (score 1):

**Probably this could help:**

```
/**********************************************************************
 * Complexity:
 * This algorithm makes exactly one comparison on each step.
 * On each step - algorithm divide initial array of size n :
 * on 3 arrays with (2*n / 3) sizes
 *                                           N
 *                                       /   |   \
 *                                   2N/3  2N/3  2N/3
 *                                   /
 *                              (2N/3)2/3
 *                                 /
 *                               ...
 *                               /
 *                           N * (2/3)^k = 1
 * By considering this tree we can find the depth - k:
 * N * (2/3)^k = 1                  =>>
 * N = 1 / (2/3)^k                  =>>
 * N = (3/2)^k                      =>>
 * log(3/2, N) = log(3/2, (3/2)^k)  =>>
 * k = log(3/2, N) (!!!)
 *
 * On each step algorithm makes 3^k comparisons =>> on the last step we will get:
 *                                     3^(log(3/2, N)) =>> N^(log(3/2, 3))
 * comparisons.
 *
 * We can compute the full work:
 * 1 + 3 + 9 + ... + 3^(log(3/2, N))
 * by using geometric progression formulas.
 * 
 *************************************************************************/
public static void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo >= hi) return;
    if (less(a[hi], a[lo])) exch(a, hi, lo);
    if (hi - lo + 1 > 2) {
        int t = (hi - lo + 1) / 3;
        sort(a, lo, hi - t);
        sort(a, lo + t, hi);
        sort(a, lo, hi - t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we define T(n) as the answer (j-i+1 = n) we have:
T(n) = 3*T(n/1.5) + O(1)

You can solve that using [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) and the answer will be theta(n^log(3,1.5)) = theta(n^(log 3 / log 1.5))

You can prove that using induction on n too.

Using recursion tree is acceptable too:
k = number of levels = log (n,1.5)
ans = 1 + 3 + 3^2 + ... + 3^k = theta(3^k) = theta(3^log(n,1.5)) = theta(n^log(3,1.5))

Answer (score -2):

t(n) = 3⋅t(2*n/3) + Θ(n)

h = 1+log<sub>3/2</sub>(n)

Try to calculate. it is easy.

At every level we have complexity 3<sup>i</sup>⋅c, where c is some constant and i is the height of that particular level

t(n) = Σ<sub>i=0,...,h</sub> c⋅3<sup>i</sup>

t(n) = n-2<sup>log₃(n)</sup>/2<sup>log₃(n)+1</sup>

then its a simple geometric progression.